# Read only specific text pattern in Google Vision

Tags: android, google-vision

I'm using Google Mobile Vision (Android) to detect text in documents. My question is can we limit the detecting all text at the initial stage and look only for specific text pattern?

```
@Override
public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {
    SparseArray<TextBlock> items = detections.getDetectedItems();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {

    }
}
```

This method will retrieve all the text blocks detected. It's not possible to implement a way to find the string pattern inside this, because this will trigger when new text detected and there is no time to check the condition with all text blocks.

Is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean you need to detect specific portion of the image ? I doubt you can do that. Why not crop the image and pass to GVision.

Comment: I need this in real-time. Also I'm not trying to get a portion of the image. What I need is to check for specific set of words in the whole image (actually live camera)

Comment: I don't think you can do that as of now. You might want to match after retrieving the text from GVision, only option I guess

Comment: Is it only giving text blocks data?. As far as I know there must be a description data that you can get from text annotations. Then you can easily search a string from description.